# Creating a Public Typealias to Combine Multiple Protocols in One Swift Package/Target and Conforming to It in Other Targets

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols, type-alias

I'm working on a Swift project where I have defined several protocols in one package/target, and I want to create a typealias that combines these protocols. My intention is to use this typealias in other targets and conform to it. However, I'm facing some challenges achieving this.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

In my first Swift package/target (PackageA), I have defined two protocols:

```
// PackageA.swift
public protocol ProtocolA {
    func methodA()
}

public protocol ProtocolB {
    func methodB()
}
```

Now, I want to create a typealias that combines these two protocols. So, I tried the following:

```
// PackageA.swift
public typealias CombinedProtocol = ProtocolA & ProtocolB
```

However, this results in a compiler error. It seems like Swift doesn't allow directly creating a typealias that combines multiple protocols.

My question is, how can I achieve this? Is there a way to create a public typealias that combines multiple protocols in one package/target and then use it to conform to in other targets?

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I attempted to create the `typealias` directly in the package where
   the protocols are defined...
2. Then I've tried importing the package where the typealias is defined into the target where I want to conform to it, but the compiler couldn't "see" my `typealias" and I had to redeclare it in that target to make the idea work.

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am wondering about the file which contains `typealias CombinedProtocol`, did it select target correctly? Because declaring `public alias` like above seems valid.

Comment: What do you mean by "did it select target correctly"? It's the same file that contains all of the three other protocols.

Comment: I meant these protocol files Target Membership. I've tried on a new Framework target, and everything seemed to be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I've found also inconsistent behavior with this.

Comment: Try associatedType

Comment: I think it has worked for me now in the same project. I cannot understand the root cause tbh.